# Getting into all entries by querySelectorAll in JS

Tags: javascript

Yesterday, I've asked the same, by today I'm little more specific. I want to get those div values into the generated link, so link would be like: `https://stackoverflow.com/value1 value2 value3`

```
<div class="example">value 1</div>

<div class="example">value 2</div>

<div class="example">value 3</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.querySelectorAll('.example');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].innerText;
} 

    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/'+x ,'_blank', "width=550, height=550");
}
</script>
```

All i'm getting is `https://stackoverflow.com/[object NodeList]`
Can you help me how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

> All i'm getting is https://stackoverflow.com/[object NodeList] Can you
>   help me how to handle this?

Because `x` is still the `nodeList` and you are not assigning anything to `x`, you need another accumulator

```
var value = [];
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    value.push( x[i].innerText);
} 
value = value.join(" "); //not sure why you need space delimited values

window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/'+value  ,'_blank', "width=550, height=550");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just having the line `x[i].innerText;` on its own returns the value of `innerText` but crucially you're not storing the result anywhere.

In the `window.open()` function the value of x is an object not a string.